# How do I access submitted params in a rails mailer?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a previous question that helped me loop through all users where a certain question is met.

However, I'm realizing I can't hard code that condition. I need to somehow get that data from the submitted form, which doesn't seem to be possible in the mailer.

In other words, I'm trying to loop through all users where the user's state is equal to the home_state of the candidate being entered. Basically when the candidate is created, I want to get the home_state of that candidate, and then loop through all users, and for each user that has same state as that candidate, I want to send them the email via this mailer.

Here's my candidate_mailer.rb file

```
class CandidateMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'wesleycreations@gmail.com'

  def self.send_request(row)

    @candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params) # if I can access this here, how to I create the 
                                                 # following array? 
    emails = []
    User.where(state: @candidate.home_state).each do |u|
      emails << u.email # To insert the user email into the array
    end

    emails.each do |email|
      new_request(email,row).deliver_now
    end
  end

  def new_request(email, row)
    @candidate = row
    mail(to: email, subject: 'New request')
  end
end
```

But the

```
@candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)
```

obviously doesn't work because the params aren't available in the mailer.

Here in the candidates_controller.rb I have this

```
def create
    @candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params) #of course here I can access params
    if @candidate.save
      row = @candidate
      CandidateMailer.send_request(row)
    else
    render('new')
    end
end
```

SO the question is, how do I access params in rails mailer? And if I can't, then how do I refactor my code so that the lines that check if the user meets certain condition is done in the controller?

Comment: You're already passing a user record into the mailer via `send_request`. You don't have to pass params again. If you did, for whatever reason, you could just make another argument.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure this out by doing this. after I saved the candidate, I saved the candidate to a global variable. and THEN I send the mailer.

```
  def create
    @candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)
    if @candidate.save
      row = @candidate
      $candidate = @candidate
      end
    CandidateMailer.send_request(row)
    else
    end
  end
```

This way the mailer had access to the new candidate that been created, and I was able to check my condition in there.

So in my mailer, when I use $candidate.home_state, it returned the correct state, mail went out, and made me very happy :)

```
    emails = []
    User.where(state: $candidate.home_state).each do |u|
      emails << u.email # To insert the user email into the array
    end
```

Comment: No, don't use globals .... you are already passing `@candidate` into the mailer as `row` ...